Is an ergodic dynamical system, whose underlying space is connected, totally ergodic?
All the examples of ergodic non-totally ergodic dynamical systems that I know of consist of a disconnected space (e.g. a finite space). Therefore my question is:
Let $X$ be a compact connected space, $T:X\to X$ a homeomorphism and $\mu$ an ergodic Borel $T$-invariant probability measure on $X$. Is $(X,T,\mu)$ totally ergodic?
In addition, any references in the literature regarding this question would be appreciated.

Hint: Consider the wedge of two 2-dimensional tori.

Thanks for the hint! I tried to construct a counterexample based on your comment. Is this what you had in mind?

Based on Moishe Kohan's comment, let me give an example of connected ergodic system which is not totally ergodic:
Let $X = \mathbb{T}^2 \vee  (\mathbb{T}^2)'$ be the wedge sum of two tori, identified at the point $0$. Denote by $x$ and $x'$ elements of $X$ that belong to $\mathbb{T}^2$ and $(\mathbb{T}^2)'$ respectively.
Let $A$ be an ergodic automorphism of $\mathbb{T}^2$, and define $T:X\to X$ by $Tx = (Ax)'$ and $T(x') = Ax $. It is well-defined since $A0=0$. The measure $\mu$ is the normalized area measure.
To see that it is ergodic, let $E\subset X$ be $T$-invariant. Then $E\cap \mathbb{T}^2$ is $T^2 = A^2$-invariant. Ergodic toral automorphisms are totally ergodic with respect to Haar measure, so $E\cap\mathbb{T}^2$ must be null or co-null with respect to Haar measure, and hence so is $E$ with respect to $\mu$.
However, $\mathbb{T}^2$ is $T^2$-invariant so the system is not totally ergodic.

Right.... ......
